# Delete contents of table and replace using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to delete the contents of a  upon click and repopulate it based on what they are clicking.

I was able to succesfully modify the  with the new title, but I keep running into issues when I want to delete the contents of  and replace it with a new one. I've tried doing the removeChild(), the replaceChild(), as well as innerHTML (which doesn't work based on documentation).

How would I successfully on a click, remove the existing table and repopulate it with HTML generated from JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<table id="captable" border = "5" width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="5">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="100%">
            <div id="table-title"></div>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <th>Input Date</th>
      <th>Requested Date</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tbodyid">
      <div id="table-entries">
         <tr align = "center">
            <td>3/27/2018</td>
            <td>6/12/2018</td>
         </tr>
      </div>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
   function(evt) {
       $("#table-title").html("<h2><b>" + Title + ":</b><i> " + Subtitle + "</i></h2>");
       var tBodyInner;
       for (i of dataPoints) {
           console.log("data" + i);
           var data = json.Data[i];
           tBodyInner += ("<tr align = \"center\">");
           tBodyInner += ("<td><a target=\"_blank\" href=" + data.cap_url + ">" + data.capNumber + "</a></td>");

           tBodyInner += ("</tr>");
       }
       //Not sure what to do here so that I clear the existing table, and appened the new tBodyInner html as a replacement
       modal.style.display = "block";
   }
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `<div>` as a child of `<tbody>`. Its children have to be `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to get rid of `<div id="table-entries">`, this is not a valid location for a DIV.

Second, you need to initialize the variable `tBodyInner` to an empty string.

Finally, you can use `$("#tbodyId").html()` to fill in the HTML of the table body.

```js
function(evt) {
  $("#table-title").html("<h2><b>" + Title + ":</b><i> " + Subtitle + "</i></h2>");
  var tBodyInner = "";
  for (i of dataPoints) {
    console.log("data" + i);
    var data = json.Data[i];
    tBodyInner += ("<tr align = \"center\">");
    tBodyInner += ("<td><a target=\"_blank\" href=" + data.cap_url + ">" + data.capNumber + "</a></td>");

    tBodyInner += ("</tr>");
  }
  $("#tBodyId").html(tBodyInner);
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<table id="captable" border="5" width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="100%">
        <div id="table-title"></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <th>Input Date</th>
    <th>Requested Date</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbodyid">
    <tr align="center">
      <td>3/27/2018</td>
      <td>6/12/2018</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you exactly change the html inside the element? You are setting the variable `tBodyInner`, but never using it. You should use it like you updated the title above, for example:

```
$("#table-entries").html(tBodyInner);
```

Also the parentheses around the string concats on the right side are redundant. No harm, but no effect either.